# Angle between two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have been taught that the angle between two vectors is supposed to be their inner product. However, the book I'm reading states:

> Recall that the angle between two vectors $u = (u_0,\ldots,u_{n−1})$ and $v = (v_0,\ldots, v_{n−1})$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ (the complex plane) is just a scaling factor times their *inner product*.

What is a "scaling factor"?

Comment: This is wrong. The angle between two vectors $u$ and $v$ is $\cos^{-1} \left( \frac{u \cdot v}{||u|| ||v||} \right)$.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: That would be for real vectors

Comment: @Farhad What book is this from? It seems poorly worded, at best.

Comment: @MichaelBoratko It's from "Algorithms" by S.Dasgupta, page 73. Mathematically, it's not the greatest book but it does provide creative computer science algorithms.

Comment: The statement reflects that the notion of an angle between two vectors in an inner product space depends on the inner product. The dot product described in some answers below is not the only admissible inner product, and so simply defining the angle by the dot product is a special case, not a general definition of the angle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your statement that

> the angle between two vectors is supposed to be their inner product

is incorrect, as is the statement from the book. [On the Wikipedia page on the dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Complex_vectors), you can see the correct formula for the angle between two complex vectors $u$ and $v$ (thanks to Henry for catching the earlier mistake):
$$\theta=\arccos\left(\frac{\operatorname{Re}(u\cdot v)}{\|u\|\|v\|}\right)$$
where the inner product $u\cdot v$ is defined to be 
$$u\cdot v=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} u_k\overline{v_k}$$
I would guess that perhaps the intended meaning of the "scaling factor" is as follows: when $u$ and $v$ **are unit vectors**, we have
$$\cos(\theta)=\operatorname{Re}(u\cdot v)$$
while when $u$ and $v$ are arbitrary non-zero vectors, we have
$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{\operatorname{Re}(u\cdot v)}{\|u\|\|v\|}$$
(the quantities $\|u\|$ and $\|v\|$ are both equal to $1$ when $u$ and $v$ are unit vectors). This would make $$\frac{1}{\|u\|\|v\|}$$
the "scaling factor", though it is scaling the formula for the *cosine of the angle*, not the angle itself.

Comment: Thanks! Assuming that the author made a mistake, what is a "scaling factor"?

Comment: I've added what I assume was intended.

Comment: If you go further down the wikipedia page to "Complex vectors", it says the angle between two complex vectors is then given by
$$\cos\theta = \frac{\operatorname{Re}(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})}{\|\mathbf{a}\|\,\|\mathbf{b}\|}.$$  Otherwise you will be taking the arccosine of a complex number.

Comment: @Henry: Thank you for pointing that out, I've corrected my answer.

Comment: What does the function $Re(a \cdot b)$ do? Sorry, I just have a limited degree of knowledge with complex vectors.

Comment: $Re(something)$ is the real value of the argument. "something" is typically a complex number. so $Re(a+bi)=a$.

Comment: @Henry What's wrong with taking arcosine of a complex number?

Comment: @Andrew:  In general it will not give you a real angle

Comment: @Henry If the inner product can take complex values, it seems silly to discard complex values of an entirely holomorphic function of that product, no? What motivation is there to restrict the values of "the angle between two vectors" instead of naturally allowing it to take values in the field over which the vector space is defined?

Comment: So, is this wrong? atan2(norm(cross(a,b)), dot(a,b)) from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330451/angle-between-two-vectors-matlab

Comment: @Pedro77: No, it's not wrong. For two vectors $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, it's true that
$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\|\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}\|}{\mathbf{a} \cdot\mathbf{b}}\right) =\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\|\mathbf{a}\|\|\mathbf{b}\| \sin(\theta)}{\|\mathbf{a}\| \|\mathbf{b} \|\cos(\theta)}\right)= \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}\right)= \tan^{-1}(\tan(\theta))=\theta$$
As was explained in the answer you linked to, that approach is chosen for numerical stability, which is a computational concern. Two formulas can both be correct but have different stability.

Comment: @Pedro77: However, my answer is correct formula for any two vectors in any $\mathbb{C}^n$. Note that the cross product of two vectors doesn't even make sense unless they are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)).

Answer (score 8):

Let $\vec{a},\vec{b}\in \mathbb{C}^n$ be nonzero, where $\vec{a} = (a_1,...,a_n)$ and $\vec{b} = (b_1,...,b_n)$. As a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, the space $\mathbb{C}^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. That is, for $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ there corresponds vectors $\vec{x},\vec{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (respectively) such that
$$
\vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix} \text{Re}\,(a_1) \\
\text{Im}\,(a_1) \\
\text{Re}\,(a_2) \\
\text{Im}\,(a_2) \\
\vdots \ \\
\text{Re}\,(a_n) \\
\text{Im}\,(a_n) \end{pmatrix} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \vec{y} = \begin{pmatrix} \text{Re}\,(b_1) \\
\text{Im}\,(b_1) \\
\text{Re}\,(b_2) \\
\text{Im}\,(b_2) \\
\vdots \ \\
\text{Re}\,(b_n) \\
\text{Im}\,(b_n) \end{pmatrix} \ .
$$

Recall that $||\,\vec{x}+\vec{y}\,||^2 = ||\, \vec{x}\, ||^2 + ||\,\vec{y}\,||^2+2\,\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}$ and
$$
\cos\theta = \frac{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}}{||\,\vec{x}\,||\,||\,\vec{y}\,||} \ ,
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ (and also the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$).

$\quad$  We will now show that $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y} = \text{Re}\,(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})$. It is easy to show that
$$
||\,\vec{a}+\vec{b}\,||^2 = ||\,\vec{a}\,||^2+||\,\vec{b}\,||^2 + \vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} + \overline{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}
$$
and
$$
||\,\vec{x}+\vec{y}\,||^2 = ||\,\vec{x}\,||^2+||\,\vec{y}\,||^2+2\,\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}.
$$
It is also easily show that $||\,\vec{x}\,|| = ||\,\vec{a}\,||$ and $||\,\vec{y}\,||=||\,\vec{b}\,||$. Consequently, $||\,\vec{x}+\vec{y}\,|| = ||\,\vec{a}+\vec{b}\,||$. Therefore, $||\,\vec{a}+\vec{b}\,||^2 = ||\,\vec{a}\,||^2+||\,\vec{b}\,||^2+2\,\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}.$ We thus obtain
$$
\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} + \overline{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}} \right).
$$

$\quad$ But observe that $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} = \alpha + i\beta$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} + \overline{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}} = (\alpha + i\beta)+(\alpha-i\beta) = 2\alpha = 2\text{Re}\,(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}).
$$
Hence,
$$
\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} + \overline{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}} \right) = \text{Re}\,(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}).
$$

And thus we finally have
$$
\cos\theta = \frac{\text{Re}\,(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})}{||\,\vec{a}\,||\,||\,\vec{b}\,||} \ .
$$
Therefore,
$$
\theta = \arccos \frac{\text{Re}\,(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})}{||\,\vec{a}\,||\,||\,\vec{b}\,||}.
$$

Comment: How you come up with it, you wrote it is very easy to proof,
$||a⃗ +b⃗ ||^2=||a⃗ ||^2+||b⃗ ||^2+a⃗ ⋅b⃗ +\overline{a⃗ ⋅b⃗ }$. I could not follow you with this can you please give some more detail on it. thank

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: @Kiran $\|\vec{a}+\vec{b}\|^2 = (\vec{a}+\vec{b})^H(\vec{a}+\vec{b}) = \vec{a}^H\vec{a} + \vec{b}^H\vec{b} + \vec{a}^H\vec{b} + \vec{b}^H\vec{a} = \|\vec{a}\|^2 + \|\vec{b}\|^2 + \vec{a}^H\vec{b} + (\vec{a}^H\vec{b})^H = \|\vec{a}\|^2 + \|\vec{b}\|^2 + 2\Re(\vec{a}^H\vec{b})$ where $(\cdot)^H$ is the Hermitian form (conjugate transpose).

Answer (score 0):

The dot product, inner product or scalar product is defined as:
$$\vec u \cdot \vec v = u_1\cdot v_1 + \ldots + u_n\cdot v_n = \|\vec u\|\cdot\|\vec v\|\cdot\cos(\angle\vec u\vec v)$$
In other words, if the two vectors are unit vectors, their dot product is the cosine of the angle between them. To get to that point, simply normalize the two vectors:
$$\frac{\vec u}{\|\vec u\|}\cdot\frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|}=\frac{\vec u \cdot \vec v}{\|\vec u\|\cdot\|\vec v\|}=\cos(\angle\vec u\vec v)$$
Take the arcus cosine of the quotient and you get the actual angle.

Comment: This formula is only correct when $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. the numbers $u_i$ and $v_i$ are real numbers. The correct formula for complex vectors (which are what are asked about in the question) is given in my answer.

Comment: Oops, missed that.